# I need to display prime numbers between two numbers

Tags: java

I have a school assignment where I need to prompt the user for two numbers and display all the prime numbers in between I can't figure it out for the life of me. Here is my code, all it does is end as soon as I enter the two numbers.

```
public static void pg150Exersize1B() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num, counter, num2;
    System.out.println("Enter your low number");
    num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your high number");
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    counter = num;
    while (num != num2) {
        counter++;
        if (num % counter == 0) {
            if (counter == num) {
                System.out.println(counter);
                num++;
            } else {
                num++;
            }
        } else{
            num++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that checks whether a number actually is prime. Would be a good point to start with. Probably move this portion of code to a separate things to keep things more readable. Thanks for your honesty regarding the fact, that this is homework.

Comment: Your `if` has 3 cases that are all doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in solving any coding-problem would be to transform the textual task into a basic code structure.

As an example, we can translate the task into the following main-routine:

> display all prime numbers between two given numbers

could be translated to

> print all numbers in a given range, if they are prime

which can be translated to the following pseudocode:

```
for i in [lower,upper]
    if isPrime(i)
        print(i)
```

This pseudocode can be translated pretty simple into the correct java-code.

Now we're missing one additional piece: the function `isPrime(...)`. So let's apply the same pattern:

> check, if a given number is prime

add some mathematical knowledge:

> a number n is prime, if it's not divisible by any number in range [2,n)

and we wind up with

> check, if a given number n isn't divisible by any number in the range [2,n)

I'll leave figuring the rest out to you.

Thanks for being honest and making clear this is homework.